# calling a function from oracle in C# giving error

Tags: c#, oracle, oracle11g

I am calling a function from oracle package which will return a string as below

```
using(OracleConnection con = AppConn.Connection)
{
    OracleCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Connection = con;
    cmd.CommandText = "select P_Pkg.found(@p_id) from dual";
    OracleParameter p_id = new OracleParameter();
    p_id.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Int64;
    p_id.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
    p_id.Value = requestHeader.approval_id;

    cmd.Parameters.Add(p_id);
    try
    {
        con.Open();
        string found = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();

    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {

    }
    finally
    {
        con.Close();
    }
}
```

but i am getting the below error . I can't find the problem after a lot of search. Please help.

> ORA-06550: line 1, column 51:
>
> PL/SQL: ORA-00936: missing expression
>
> ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:

Function signature in oracle

```
P_Pkg.found(p_id IN NUMBER) 
RETURN varchar2 //(YES , NO)
```

I run this from oracle as below and got the result with out any error

```
select P_Pkg.found(1053) from dual
```

Comment: @patrickHofman edited question

Comment: Can't you set `CommandText` to just `P_Pkg.found` and then add the parameter giving it the correct name? (`p_id`)

Comment: @codroipo how to do it?

Answer (score 3):

The problem lies in the use of the SQL Server specific prefix for parameters / bind variables. Oracle uses `:` instead of `@`. The SQL parser doesn't understand your query now.

Use this code instead:

```
select P_Pkg.found(:p_id) from dual
```

Comment: it's giving me the erro `ORA-06550: line 1, column 75:

PL/SQL: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:`

Comment: `select P_Pkg.found(1053) from dual` from toad is working fine

Comment: u need entire pckg? or only the function im calling?

Comment: Toad executes a statement, in C# you are telling that the type of the command is `StoredProcedure`, your statement may work if you specify `CommandText`

Comment: Just a dummy package would do, if you can reproduce the issue with it.

Comment: @codroipo didn't understand how to achieve that

Answer (score 3):

To call a stored procedure you just have to set the command text to the stored procedure name, then add the parameters with the correct name

```
using (OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(AppConn.Connection))
{
    using (OracleCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand())
    {
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Connection = con;
        cmd.CommandText = "P_Pkg.found";
        OracleParameter p_id = new OracleParameter();
        p_id.ParameterName = "p_id";
        p_id.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Int64;
        p_id.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
        p_id.Value = requestHeader.approval_id;
        OracleParameter retVal = new OracleParameter();
        retVal.ParameterName = "ReturnValue";
        retVal.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Varchar2; // Whatever the type the SP returns
        retVal.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;

        cmd.Parameters.Add(p_id);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(retVal);
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            string found = cmd.Parameters["ReturnValue"].Value.ToString();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
        }
    }
}
```